# How to export a Simulink model with "Drive cycle source" into FMU

Tags: matlab, simulink, fmi, simulink-library

I have a Simulink model which has as a first component a "Drive cycle source". From its settings or from the Matlab workspace i can select an xlsx file used as input for the whole model. I need to export this model as a Standalone FMU, with the possibility to interact with it using the FMI standard (in particular I need to use this library [repo](https://gitlab.com/mosaik/components/mosaik-fmi)). What I want to do is to give to it an xlsx file not directly from the block or form the workspace, but as input as defined in the fmi standard, making the FMU input-independent.

The problem is that when I try to do that an error occurs.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5LVt.png)
Moreover if I try to export as FMU the model with a selected xlsx file another error occurs.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9TnE.jpg)

So, the question is, how can I solve? (sorry for my English, and thanks in advance)

Comment: This problem seems to be Simulink specific. Which way to export the FMU do you use? (Simulink Compliler?)